# Selenium WebDriver cannot find browser in default location

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, rpa

I'm trying to learn web test automation with Selenium and I'm facing the following issue:
I created a virtual environment and installed all python libraries needed, it might be important to mention that I want to use Robot Framework with the SeleniumLibrary.
I use PopOS, so I downloaded the appropriate geckodriver to work with the Firefox installation that comes preinstalled in the OS.
I wrote a basic script based on the example provided by the SeleniumLibrary developers and ran it.
Then I got the error *Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.* So I'm failing to open the browser.
What is weird to me is that the firefox executable is in /usr/bin as expected, so I have no clue on what I could do in this situation.
I'm using the latest available stable versions of the webdrivers and browser.

I thought that the issue might be the virtual environment trying to access something that it is not allowed, so I tried changing the access permissions of the firefox executable but nothing changed.

EDIT: I tried adding the path to the Firefox binary using FirefoxOptions from selenium webdriver as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions


options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary=r"/usr/bin/firefox"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

But still no success... Now it returns InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable

Again, the file I'm pointing to is a Firefox executable and opens it normally.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify binary for the browser.

```
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = '/path/to/binary'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
```

Comment: I might try this later. I guess I'll have to use a python scripts for that as I tried using the keywords included in the SeleniumLibrary for Robot before.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. I added more information to the question. Thank you for your answer nonetheless.